# Java, CriteriaBuilder, ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I've tried to use CriteriaBuilder instead of writing queries, but when I'm testing it it gives and error and ResultSet couldn't be extracted.
My part of code in service:

```
public List getCategories(String responsibleGroupId) throws Exception {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<SublogTypeMapV> query = builder.createQuery(SublogTypeMapV.class);
    Root<SublogTypeMapV> root = query.from(SublogTypeMapV.class);
    List<Predicate> andPredicates = new ArrayList<>();

    Predicate categoryIdNotNull = builder.isNotNull(root.get(SublogTypeMapV_.categoryId));
    Predicate categotyIdGt = builder.gt(root.get(SublogTypeMapV_.categoryId), 0);
    String[] responsibleGroupListString = responsibleGroupId.split(",");
    Long[] responsibleGroupListLong = new Long[responsibleGroupListString.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < responsibleGroupListString.length; i++) {
        responsibleGroupListLong[i] = Long.valueOf(responsibleGroupListString[i]);
    }
    Predicate responsibleGroup = root.get(SublogTypeMapV_.responsibleGroupId).in(responsibleGroupListLong);
    Predicate getCategories;
    if (responsibleGroupId != null && !responsibleGroupId.equals("0"))
        getCategories = builder.and(categoryIdNotNull, categotyIdGt, responsibleGroup);
    else
        getCategories = builder.and(categoryIdNotNull, categotyIdGt);
    andPredicates.add(getCategories);
    Predicate resultPredicate = builder.and(andPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

    query.select(root).where(resultPredicate);
    return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

My part of code in TestAPI:

```
@GetMapping("typemap/getcategories")
public List<SublogTypeMapV> getCategories(@RequestParam String responsibleGroupId) throws Exception{
    return typeMapService.getCategories(responsibleGroupId);
}
```

Query generated by hibernate:

```
14:06:33,608 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Hibernate: 
14:06:33,608 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     select
14:06:33,608 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         sublogtype0_.type_map_id as type_map_id1_7_,
14:06:33,608 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         sublogtype0_.category as category2_7_,
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         sublogtype0_.category_id as category_id3_7_,
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         sublogtype0_.keyword as keyword4_7_,
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         sublogtype0_.responsible_group_id as responsible_group_5_7_,
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         sublogtype0_.subtype as subtype6_7_,
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         sublogtype0_.subtype_id as subtype_id7_7_,
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         sublogtype0_.type as type8_7_,
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         sublogtype0_.type_id as type_id9_7_ 
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     from
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         reglr.sublog_type_map_v sublogtype0_ 
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     where
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         (
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             (
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)                 sublogtype0_.category_id is not null 
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             )
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         )
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         and(
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             (
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)                 sublogtype0_.category_id>0L 
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             )
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         )
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         and(
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             (
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)                 sublogtype0_.responsible_group_id in(
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)                     7703L , 7702L
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)                 )
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             )
14:06:33,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         )
```

And finally, the error:

```
14:06:34,050 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1) SQL Error: 907, SQLState: 42000
14:06:34,050 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1) ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

For me it seems the parenthesis are generated fine, I also tried to run this query in sql developer and it works. I've spent few hours trying to find a solution, but couldn't find anything useful.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the query that goes to the database? 0L and 7703L looks like Java Long and not like a database value?

Comment: Of course, I didn't copy-paste completely, but made similar query in sql with data 7703, 7702